# Override Ctrl-C

Tags: c++, c, linux, signals

I am supposed override the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> signal and use it to print a message. It is not supposed to end the program.

What happens so far is that when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is pressed it prints the message, but ends the program.

When I asked my professor he told me to do this:
You need to make your signal handler keep from continuing to process the signal.  Right now the signal is being handled by your code and then going on to the parent handler.

Is there a method I am supposed to add or do i need to move the signal installers someplace?

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h> 
#include "Input.h"
#include "CircleBuff.h"

//void handler_function(int signal_id);

void catch_int(int sig_num){

    //reset the signal handler again to catch_int, for next time
    signal(SIGINT, catch_int);
    //print message
    printf("Print History");
    fflush(stdout);
}

void printHistory(CircleBuff hist){
    cout << "Complete History:\n" << endl;
    hist.print();
    cout << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

  struct sigaction signal_action;                /* define table */
  signal_action.sa_handler = catch_int;   /* insert handler function */
  signal_action.sa_flags = 0;                    /* init the flags field */
  sigemptyset( &signal_action.sa_mask );     /* are no masked interrupts */
  sigaction( SIGINT, &signal_action, NULL ); /* install the signal_action */

  do{


  //My code: where the value report will be assigned within.

  } while(report != 1)

}
```

Comment: You should NOT call `printf` from inside a signal handler because `printf` is not async-safe.  See `man 7 signal` for a list of async-safe functions.  The simpler `write` syscall is async safe, but none of the `<stdio.h>` functions are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whoa, *way* too much code to sift through. However, if you use the C standard library, you should get the desired behaviour. Here's a C++ version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>

sig_atomic_t sigflag = 0;

void sighandler(int s)
{
  // std::cerr << "Caught signal " << s << ".\n"; // this is undefined behaviour
  sigflag = 1; // something like that
}

int main()
{
  std::signal(SIGINT, sighandler);

  // ... your program here ...

  // example: baby's first loop (Ctrl-D to end)
  char c;
  while (std::cin >> c)
  {
    if (sigflag != 0) { std::cerr << "Signal!\n"; sigflag = 0; }
  }
}
```

This will catch `Ctrl-C` (which raises `SIGINT`), and the signal handler is not replaced, so it'll fire every time, and nobody is terminating the program.

Note that signal handlers are inherited by `fork()`ed children.

The Posix function `sigaction()` allows you to register "one-shot" handlers which are replaced by the standard handler after they're invoked once. That's more advanced and Posix-specific, though.

*Edit:* As @Dietrich points out, you should never do any real work *inside* a signal handler. Rather, you should set a flag (I provided an example), and check for that flag inside your loop (and print the message there). I'll amend the example for that, too.

Comment: It is *very unsafe* to use `std::cerr` inside a signal handler.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Unsafe or unpredictable? What's the worst that could happen? Surely the right thing to do is set a flag and move on, but that'd complicate the example. I'll make a note, though.

Comment: thanks for your input. I'll try that option, unfortunately the professor wants us to handle signals using c methods.

(I also shortened the code to include only the important material)

Comment: @ensantos91: It's literally the same in C, minus the `std::`. Also, why did you tag this C++ if you didn't want to talk about C++??

Comment: Unsafe, since you could be using `cerr` in the main thread at the same time, and both could be reading and modifying the state of the `cerr` buffer.  I would expect programs that do this to at best exhibit rare unexpected behavior and crashes, and at worst create a serious security vulnerability.  (There are a number of known security vulnerabilities resulting from poorly designed signal handlers in servers.)

Comment: @Kerrek, thanks!
The reason I tagged it as c++ is that the code is mostly in c++.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Your link in the other comment actually explains (in Posix, at least) that calling any function not listed as async-safe is *undefined behaviour*. Thanks!

Comment: for the flag check, do I just need to put it in once? or do i need to place it multiple times in my program?

Comment: @ensantos91: You need to put it everywhere where you want the program to be interruptible. So basically in every loop, or at least in every outer loop. Anything that happens *between* checks will not be aware of the signal.

Comment: @ensantos91: No problem. Don't feel shy to press that "accept" button if the answer was useful ;-)

Comment: Last question, I swear. I have a loop in another class (just an object class that waits for user input), so how would I do a flag check there?

Comment: @ensantos91: I'd put the signal handler and the flag into a header file (`extern sig_atomic_t sigflag;`), and put the definitions into a separate source file. Then you can access the flag from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that inside your while loop there may be an interruptable function failing with 'EINTR'. You could might be able to fix it by using :

```
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
```

Or, just checking errno for it and looping. Are you sure the program isn't reaching the end of termination. Try putting a print statement at the end of main.