# Preventing Ctrl-C from closing program

Tags: c++, c, linux, signals

This is an extension to a question I asked before.
[Override Ctrl-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623401/override-ctrl-c)

I have this code that is handling the signal for ctrl-c, while this worked on one machine, I ran it on another and it now once again exits the program after ctrl-c is pressed.

When I asked my professor he told me that in the handler I will need to prevent the signal from being processed further, but I am not sure how to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h> 
#include "Input.h"
#include "CircleBuff.h"

sig_atomic_t sigflag = 0;

void catch_int(int sig_num) {   
    sigflag = 1;
    //printf("to do: Print history");
}

void printHistory(CircleBuff hist) {
    cout << "Complete History:\n" << endl;
    hist.print();
    cout << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    signal(SIGINT, catch_int);

    //my code here

    do {
        //more code here
        if (sigflag != 0) {
            printHistory(history);
            sigflag = 0;            
        }
    } while(report != 0); //which is assigned in the code
```

Here is the reduced code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h> 

sig_atomic_t sigflag = 0;

void catch_int(int sig_num) {   
    sigflag = 1;
    printf("to do: Print history");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {  
    signal(SIGINT, catch_int);
    do {
    } while(1);
}
```

Comment: which system does it not work on?

Comment: @Matthew You must be kidding, this is a C problem in a .cpp file  the only thing making it C++ are streams which are irrelevant to the question

Comment: its supposed to be an ubuntu machine. I built the program in one machine and it worked fine, but i compile and run it on another (which I am assuming also runs ubuntu) and it doesnt

Comment: @nhed, I'm okay with being tagged both.  However, tagging only C was not appropriate.  Signal-handling is exactly the kind of edge case where the standards can differ.  See [this article](http://www.glenmccl.com/ansi_032.htm) for a start.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);`?

I assume that will work

---

Edit:

I went back and reduced your program just a bit and the handler seems to work
(every invokation increases the flag), yet the actual syscall (sleep in mycase) is aborted.

Can you retest and restate what is not working for you in this reduced sample?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t ctrlCcount = 0;

void catch_int(int sig_num){
  ctrlCcount++;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

  signal(SIGINT, catch_int);
  do{
     sleep(5);
     printf("Ctrl-C count=%d\n", ctrlCcount);
   }while(1);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: that worked ish. The program no longer ends when I do ctrl-c but it doesn't seem to run my signal handler setting the signal flag to 1.

Comment: @ensantos91 sorry, if you can reduce the program to a self-sufficient program that reproduces your issue it will be easier to help, as we can try it on our side.  I copied your program but guessed at the content... see edit

Comment: on a probably unrelated note, you would want to mark the variables modified by the handler as `volatile` to ensure that they are not cached in a register (and your `main` wont see the updated value)

Comment: I updated the code to my reduced form, and it still quits after ctrl c, I tried your sample code as well and it is doing the same.

Comment: I tried this on a MacOS as well as Linux (Centos5.5 on a VM hosted on my Mac), no quits.  If you say that this works on one but not on the other, what can you tell us about the differences between them?  Are the shells and shell init files identical?

Comment: I honestly think it may be the machine. I personally don't know the the details about the machines I was using, since I was using ssh to do the work.

But thank you for all your time, I'll go to my professor next week and see if I can work it out with him.