# C++ Process fork and sigalarm

Tags: c++, fork

The goal of this program is to fork and have the child sleep while parent loops infinitely waiting for an interrupt.  When I hit ^C, it calls the `void parent` function.  This part works however, the message from the  `kill ( pid, SIGALRM )` is not working.  I checked and `pid` is the correct process ID for the child.

I've searched for awhile, but I haven't found what I'm doing wrong.  I used the `kill ( pid, SIGALRM )` before from the child process to the parent but I can't figure out why this isn't working..

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;

int pid;

void parent ( int sig )
{
        kill ( pid, SIGALRM );
        cout << "I'm a parent " << getpid() << " My child is " << pid << endl;
}

void child ( int sig )
{
        cout << "I am " << getpid() << "my parent is " << getppid()<< endl;
        cout << "Use ctrl+backslash to actually end the program" << endl;
}
int main()
{
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0)
        { //Child process
                cout << "Child pid = " << getpid() << " Waiting for interrupt." << endl;
                (void) signal ( SIGALRM, child );
                pause();
        }
        else if(pid > 0)
        { //Parent
                sleep(2);
                cout << "child pid = " << pid << endl;
                struct sigaction act;
                act.sa_handler = parent;
                sigemptyset ( &act.sa_mask);
                sigaction (SIGINT, &act, 0);
                while(1)
                {
                        sleep ( 1 ); 
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the output, and what OS are you doing this on? Also, being pedantic here, those signal handlers should be defined with C linkage. (Ie, put them inside extern "C" blocks)

Comment: Also, how do you know that iostreams are safe to use in a signal handler?  I am wondering if this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623401/override-ctrl-c (But even if it is, I think this question deserves to stay as-is)

Comment: I am using Fedora 15.
The output that I get is:
`Child pid = 23779 Waiting for interrupt.`

`child pid = 23779`
`^CI'm a parent 23778 My child is 23779`
`^CI'm a parent 23778 My child is 23779`
`^\Quit (core dumped)`

And thanks for the extern C block, I've never used that before

Comment: It's not waiting for an interrupt, it got the interrupt, however how are you then handling it? I don't see logic that tells the application to close cleanly.  Are you intending to call your event handlers recursively? Do you intend your signal handler to itself send a signal (as seems to be the case here), and again, how do you know that iostreams are safe to use in a signal handler?  (It's not)

Comment: The parent handled the interrupt as expected, by outputting the "I'm a parent ..." but the part that isn't working  (or at least I don't think it is) is the `kill ( pid, SIGALRM );`  I'm expecting the interrupt handler to tell the child to output "Use ctrl+backslash to actually end the program" during the first interrupt and then the child will end.  Then I will hit ^\ to quit the parent process.
And I don't know if the iostream is safe here, I just know that I've used cout before if seperate programs using the interrupt handler and the sigalarm, and it worked there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out the problem.
When I was pressing ^C, it would catch the interrupt in the main process, but kill the child process.  When I ran a `system("ps")` from inside the program, it showed the child a.out process to be defunct.
To fix this I added the following to the child's process:

```
struct sigaction act;
act.sa_handler = CHILD_PRESERVER;
sigemptyset ( &act.sa_mask);
sigaction (SIGINT, &act, 0);
```

Where `CHILD PRESERVER` was a dummy function that did nothing except keep it alive.

It doesn't see that this solution is very elegant, so if anyone has a more correct way of doing this please post it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing as your `sigaction` solution by just using `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);`

The thing that tripped you up initially (and often trips up new programmers dealing with ctrl-C and signals) is that ctrl-C sends a signal to AN ENTIRE PROCESS GROUP, rather than to a single process -- every process in the group will get the signal.  The process group the signal is sent to is the foreground process group of the terminal.

So this gives you lots of ways of dealing with/controlling ctrl-C interrupts.  You can have each process install its own SIGINT handler (as you have done).  Or you can carefully manage your process groups, putting children into their own process group (which will generally not be the foreground process group), so they won't get the signal in the first place.

You manage process groups with the setpgrp(2)/setpgid(2) system call.