# Catch a forced exit from terminal (x button on top OR ctrl+Z)

Tags: c, linux, shell, signals

im making a chat in C using TCP connection between client and server.
Im running that on linux terminal.

First of all i run the server on one terminal, and then every client on another one.
Everything is done except one thing.

I want that the client program will catch a click on the X button on the terminal or closing the program with CTRL+C ,and before the process die send a message to the server.

There is a way to do such thing?

Thank you, Dudu.

Comment: Ctrl-Z on Linux is for *suspending* a process, not terminating it.  Did you mean Ctrl-C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override Ctrl-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623401/override-ctrl-c)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is to intercept a System Signal.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling

Comment: And which signal do i have to catch for CTRL+C and X button?

Comment: SIGINT is CTRL+C. As far as the terminal closing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5547386/1496080