# C: fprintf interrupted with Ctrl C

Tags: c++, c, stdout, stdio, printf

How do I make sure the current line will be written to file completely with a `Ctrl+C` break?
Most of the time I get a partial last line. I know it's normal, but how can I handle this?

Thank you

Comment: Each OS handles Ctrl-C a different way. What OS/build system?

Comment: Don't forget to `fflush()`?

Comment: You can catch the `Ctrl+C` with a signal handler... you can write directly to a memory mapped file instead of using `fprintf` for faster writes... you can `fflush` the `stdout` buffer after each write to ensure there's no pending activity. What are you going for? What system are you on? What's the use case for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override Ctrl-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623401/override-ctrl-c)

Comment: to chux, each line is short but string comes in very fast. fflush every line would introduce lots of overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If running Linux, You can catch the SIGINT signal and flush all your data into the file in the signal handler. Normally all processes in Linux receive SIGINT with default signal mask. All you have to do is to write signal handler function and then use sigaction() system call.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html